# Get THumbnail for video URL in dropbox in Android

Tags: android, video, dropbox, video-thumbnails, mediametadataretriever

I have been searching for a way to generate a thumbnail preview image for a video stored on Dropbox in an android app I am developing.  At this point it seems that the only way is to create a thumbnail image from the video and upload with the video, this is not desirable.

I have been looking into the mediametadataretriever.getframeattime() method but wondered if anyone know if this method works with internet urls such as a dropbox temporary link or shared link, as it does not seem to work.

Thank-you in advance for any help with this.